# How to deploy a live learning tensor flow model in cloud?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

How do I deploy a tensor flow model in cloud which can learn and update the weights when given as input . Since most of the deployment methods I saw involved model freezing which implied freezing of weights also . Is it possible or is the latter the only way ?

Answer (score 0):

Freezing the model is the most compact form and lets you have a smaller inference node which you can call for just prediction and only has the necessary information to do just that.

If you want to have and model and make it available to learn online and also make inference you could have so it has all the graph loaded with the newest weights. For security save the weights from time to time. Of course you could have two programs one for inference with the latest frozen model and another one that you up from time to time to make a new training, using the last saved weights. I recommend you the second option. Hope it helps!